# Windows to S3 move command syntax

Tags: windows, amazon-s3, mv

I'm trying to upload a bunch file from a local windows folder into S3 and running into a syntax issue:

> ```
> PS E:\sv2_test> aws s3 mv E:\test s3://opsbacklognocopy/
> move failed: .\ to s3://sv2opsbacklognocopy/ [Errno 2] 
> No such file or directory: u'E:\\sv2_test\\'
> ```

I tried different syntax combinations but to no avail. Copying files individually is not an issue. I'm probably missing something basic. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by including the --recursive clause.

Comment: You'd think that `--recursive` meant walk the subdirectories, but apparently it's confused and thinks that the `E:\test` directory is a filename. Using `E:\test\` doesn't work either.